# Consecutive Occurrences of Values

Tags: google-bigquery

I have to conduct a count of **CONSECUTIVE** occurrences by date of student absences.

Within two categories: **2 consecutive fouls/absences** and **3 or more consecutive fouls**.

*Data example:*

| Name | Date | Present |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Student 1 | 2022/01/01 | false |
| Student 1 | 2022/01/02 | false |
| Student 1 | 2022/01/03 | true |
| Student 1 | 2022/01/04 | false |
| Student 1 | 2022/01/05 | false |
| Student 1 | 2022/01/06 | false |
| Student 1 | 2022/01/07 | true |
| Student 1 | 2022/01/08 | false |
| Student 1 | 2022/01/09 | false |
| Student 1 | 2022/01/10 | false |
| Student 1 | 2022/01/11 | false |
| Student 1 | 2022/01/12 | true |
| Student 1 | 2022/01/13 | false |
| Student 1 | 2022/01/14 | false |
| Student 1 | 2022/01/15 | true |

***Expected outcome:***

| Students | Count 2 Consecutive Absences | Count 3 consecutives or more | Total of Absences |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Student 1 | 2 | 2 | 11 |

I tried to conduct this code using LAG and OVER, but I wasn't successful.

```
CASE WHEN LAG(present) OVER (order by date) is false AND present is false THEN 1 END as test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select name, 
  countif(absences = 2) as Count_2_Consecutive_Absences,
  countif(absences > 2) as Count_3_or_more_Consecutive_Absences,
  sum(absences) as Total_Absences,
from (
  select name, countif(not present) absences
  from (
    select *, countif(new_grp) over(partition by name order by date) grp
    from (
      select *, ifnull(present != lag(present) over(partition by name order by date), true) new_grp
      from your_table
    )
  )
  group by name, grp
  having absences > 0
)
group by name
```

if applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps and islands problem, and once approach uses the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Date) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Present ORDER BY Date) rn2
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT Name,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN Present = false THEN 1 END) AS num_consec_absent
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY Name, rn1 - rn2
)

SELECT Name,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN num_consec_absent = 2
                  THEN 1 END) AS Count_2_Consecutive_Absences,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN num_consec_absent > 2
                  THEN 1 END) AS Count_3_or_more_Consecutive_Absences,
       SUM(num_consec_absent) AS Total_Absences
FROM cte2
GROUP BY Name;
```

Here is a running [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3382a3289a46f85633c3e63012b8eaa7) for SQL Server.